# Ordem de execução dos teste unitários

Tags: php

Existe alguma forma de definir a ordem de execução dos métodos de testes ?

Quando coloco o código da função `testSelectDaInsercao` dentro de `testInsercaoDeDados` os teste são executados com sucesso, porém desse jeito o teste falha. Acredito que seja devido a ordem de execução.

Procurei na documentação e vi apenas algo sobre `depends`e lá deixava claro que isso não alteraria a ordem. Já inverti a ordem dos métodos, porém o teste também falhou !

```
use Application\Conn;
use Application\operacao;
use PHPUnit\Framework\TestCase;

class PHPTest extends TestCase 
{
    private $conn;

    public function setUp()
    {
        $this->conn = new Conn();
        $this->conn = $this->conn->retornaConexao();
    }

    public function testInsercaoDeDados()
    {      
        $stmt = $this->conn->prepare("INSERT INTO usuario values (?, ?)");

        $stmt->bindValue(1, 'teste', \PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $stmt->bindValue(2, '123456', \PDO::PARAM_STR);

        $resul = $stmt->execute();
        $this->assertTrue($resul);  
    }

    public function testSelectDaInsercao()
    {
        $resul = $this->conn->query("SELECT count(usuario.nome) as id 
                                    FROM usuario WHERE nome = 'teste' 
                                    AND senha = '123456'");

        $resul = $resul->fetch(\PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

        $resul = (int) $resul['id'];

        $this->assertEquals(1, $resul, 'erro ao comparar insercao'); 
    }

    public function tearDown()
    {           
        $this->conn->query("truncate table usuario");
    }

}
```

usando `depends` `/** * @depends testInsercaoDeDados **/`

Comment: mostre como executa isso...

Comment: Não entendi a pergunta, vc quer ver a mensagem de erro ?

Comment: se tem mensagem de erro, mostre também...

Comment: pra rodar você tem que usar o phpunit, ta ai o erro

Comment: da a mesma coisa

Comment: so coloquei {@depends} como "comentário". Não coloquei o retorno, se baseando na documentação isso não resolveria. A mesma diz : . Tais dependências não definem a ordem em que os métodos de teste devem ser executados.https://phpunit.de/manual/current/pt_br/writing-tests-for-phpunit.html#writing-tests-for-phpunit.test-dependencies

Comment: ja editei a pergunta

Comment: então, qnd eu coloco na mesma função funciona, o que significa que está inserindo. Quanto ao id,  é auto_increment. Se não estivesse inserindo o primeiro teste não teria passado, visto que o mesmo retornaria false.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seu problema não está na ordem da execução, está no método `tearDown`.

O PHPUnit irá executar os métodos `setUp` e `tearDown` **após** a execução cada [método da sua classe](https://phpunit.de/manual/6.2/pt_br/fixtures.html).

Como seu `tearDown` está dando um *truncate* na tabela toda (o que é o correto), ao executar o teste seguinte dessa classe ele irá começar com a tabela zerada novamente.

Para resolver isso, duas abordagens podem ser tomadas:

Unificar ambos os testes em um só:

```
use Application\Conn;
use Application\operacao;
use PHPUnit\Framework\TestCase;

class PHPTest extends TestCase 
{
    private $conn;

    public function setUp()
    {
        $this->conn = new Conn();
        $this->conn = $this->conn->retornaConexao();
    }

    public function testInsertAndRecoverFromDatabase()
    {      
        $stmt = $this->conn->prepare("INSERT INTO usuario values (?, ?)");

        $stmt->bindValue(1, 'teste', \PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $stmt->bindValue(2, '123456', \PDO::PARAM_STR);

        $result = $stmt->execute();
        $this->assertTrue($result);

        $selectResult = $this->conn->query("SELECT count(usuario.nome) as id 
                                    FROM usuario WHERE nome = 'teste' 
                                    AND senha = '123456'");

        $selectResult = $selectResult->fetch(\PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

        $insertedId = (int) $resul['id'];

        $this->assertEquals(1, $insertedId , 'erro ao comparar insercao'); 
    }    

    public function tearDown()
    {           
        $this->conn->query("truncate table usuario");
    }    
}
```

No lugar do `setUp` e `tearDown`, usar [`setUpBeforeClass` e `tearDownAfterClass`](https://phpunit.de/manual/6.2/pt_br/fixtures.html#fixtures.sharing-fixture). Esses são dois métodos estáticos que rodam somente na construção de toda a classe de testes. Combinado com o `@depends` você consegue garantir que ambos os testes sejam executados.

```
use Application\Conn;
use Application\operacao;
use PHPUnit\Framework\TestCase;

class PHPTest extends TestCase 
{
    private static $conn;

    public static function setUpBeforeClass()
    {
        static::$conn = (new Conn())->retornaConexao();
    }

    public function testInsertIntoDatabase()
    {      
        $stmt = static::$conn->prepare("INSERT INTO usuario values (?, ?)");

        $stmt->bindValue(1, 'teste', \PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $stmt->bindValue(2, '123456', \PDO::PARAM_STR);

        $result = $stmt->execute();
        $this->assertTrue($result);

        $selectResult = static::$conn->query("SELECT count(usuario.nome) as id 
                                    FROM usuario WHERE nome = 'teste' 
                                    AND senha = '123456'");

        $selectResult = $selectResult->fetch(\PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

        $insertedId = (int) $resul['id'];

        $this->assertEquals(1, $insertedId , 'erro ao comparar insercao'); 
    }    

    /** @depends testInsertIntoDatabase */
    public function testSelectPreviousInsertedRegister()
    {
        $resul = $this->conn->query("SELECT count(usuario.nome) as id 
                                    FROM usuario WHERE nome = 'teste' 
                                    AND senha = '123456'");

        $resul = $resul->fetch(\PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

        $resul = (int) $resul['id'];

        $this->assertEquals(1, $resul, 'erro ao comparar insercao'); 
    }

    public static function tearDownAfterClass()
    {           
        static::$conn->query("truncate table usuario");
    }    
}
```

Comment: ah sim, agora entendi esse tearDown. Tinha me equivocado quanto a sua utilização

Answer (score 1):

O problema está no método `tearDown`:

```
public function tearDown()
{           
    $this->conn->query("truncate table usuario");
}
```

Esse método é executado sempre após cada teste, seja ele válido ou com falha. Ou seja, quando o teste `testInsercaoDeDados` é executado, as informações são gravadas, mas quando o teste é finalizado, o método `tearDown` é executado limpando os registros. Quando o teste `testSelectDaInsercao` for executado, não haverá registros.

Para contornar esse problema, você pode efetuar o `truncate` da tabela no método `tearDownAfterClass`, pois este será executado apenas quando TODOS os testes forem executados, assim garantindo que os registros sejam persistidos enquanto os testes estiverem sendo executados.

Comment: elas ja estavam utilizando a mesma conexão.... Contudo após realizar essas modificações e tirar essa linha'$this->conn->query("truncate table usuario");'  do metodo tearDown e adicionar no testSelectDaInsercao o teste funcionou.... um tanto quanto estranho mas ....

Comment: Não vai funcionar por causa do tearDown